# Is it possible to use a queue inside event-listener in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-queue

Is it possible to use a queue inside event-listener in Laravel?

Lets say I have a controller `QuotesController` from where I fire the `QuoteCreated` event which has a `SendNotification` listener. And I want to dispatch a queue named `EmailToUser` from that listener.

Of course I can dispatch the queue directly form Controller but can I dispatch it form a listener?

Comment: yes you can. dispatch the queue from the `handle()` method.

Comment: I have tied but getting this error `Call to undefined method App\Jobs\EmailToUser::dispatch()`

Comment: share your code

Comment: @shuvrow use the global `dispatch()` helper method. Do not use `$this->dispatch()`.

Comment: Thanks it worked, I thinks you should put your comment in answar section now :) @jszobody

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a global [`dispatch()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-dispatch) helper method that you can use *anywhere* in a Laravel app!

```
dispatch(new SomeJob());
```

And yes you can do this from inside an event listener, or a queue job, or anything else.